# How to change items color in gridview in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

am doing one application here am displaying A to Z values using textview in gridview,after that when i click alphabet am going to some other activity..up to that i did,my problem is if i click "A" alphabet then i have to go Activity2 then i am coming back to previous activity(GridViewAcvtivity) means now i need to show only "A" alphabet text in red color,remain all alphabets in default color,then again  i click "B" alphabet,then i will go some other Activity2 then i am coming back to GridviewActivity means that time only "A and B" alphabets should be in "red color" remain alphabets all default color..i tried using below code,once i click A alphabet,them am going to Activity2,then am coming back to GridviewActivity that time all alphabets chanaging to red color,but i want show only A alphabet in red color,any one give me some idea.

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridView;

static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "A", "B",
        "C", "D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GlobalClass.value1=1;
            Intent i=new Intent(GridViewActivity.this,Activity2.class);
            i.putExtra("k1", "position");
            startActivity(i);
            }
    });

}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

            if(GlobalClass.value1==1)
            {
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}


String mLabelsIds[]={"RED","YELLOW","black"};
      }
```

Comment: You have to make an arrayList of alphabets which you have clicked..then at the time of setting gridView u can select the color of text which are in arrayList.

Comment: thnkyou..in onitemclick i added postion into one array list..then getview method i gave like below,nut no use..if(quesid.equals(position))
    {
     textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else
    {
     textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }

Comment: You have to use like that.. if(arryList.contains(position)){textView.setTextColor(Color.RED)}else{textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW)}

Comment: thanks its working now.i used eqauls() thats why its didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

In `setOnItemClickListener()` before starting the activity change the color of the currently clicked letter. When you'll return, the text should be pre-colored already.

Something like this:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
         TextView currentLetter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
         currentLetter.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

         // start Activity2 here
     }
}
```

As a side note, provide implementations for the `getItem()` and `getItemId()` methods, otherwise you may get strange behaviours.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
   return mobileValues[position]; //return the element from array at specified position
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position; //usually the item id is its position.
}
```

Comment: thankyou..i tried your code..but when click item that time only its showing green color,if i go some other activity then come back to gridview means its not showing greencolor

Comment: It should work, just tried on my side. When you go back to GridViewActivity you use the device's BACK button, right? I mean,  that you shoul not start the activity again when coming back.

Comment: no am click button to go back inside button click i gave like this      Intent i=new Intent(Activity2.this,GridViewActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);

Comment: Well I suspect this is the problem. Actually you don't go back, but restart the `GridViewActivity` which puts it in its initial state.
Inside the button you should call: `finish()`. This way the current activity will be killed, and user will be taken back to previous activity. (as a side note, in Android in most of the cases you don't have (and shouldn't) to create a button to go back, users just use the device's BACK button)